# Selecting Face Maps

Tags: python, faces, vertex-groups, select

I'm trying to select faces by assigning them to a Face Map, and then using

```
bpy.ops.object.face_map_select(True)
```

This works, but I can't figure out how to specify which Face Map to select. It selects the active Face Map but I see no way to make a Face Map active by name or index. I tried using Vertex Groups, where I can use

```
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group="Name")

bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
```

but it selects faces I don't want since you can't define faces by its vertices without including neighboring faces.

I can even move an active Face Map up and down in the list with

```
bpy.ops.object.face_map_move(direction='UP')
```

but if I can't set the active face map I don't know what good that does.
Are Face Maps not fully implemented yet? Is there a better way to select specific faces with Python?

EDIT - I found a good way to do it with Material Slots: [How do I select vertices by material slot in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106372/how-do-i-select-vertices-by-material-slot-in-python)
However I would still like to know if it's possible with Face Maps.

Comment: For your information https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/object_data.html#face-maps

Comment: But you can  obj.face_maps.active_index = obj.face_maps['FaceMap'].index

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that.